# Node JS FS readFile not working inside res.render

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, fs

Simple and straightforward, the following returns server error. res.json never runs.
res.app.render works and renders html when I run res.send(html)
fs works independently if I put it outside res.app.render

```
 app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
res.app.render(data.template, { //requires a nice template
            data: data
        }, function (err, html) {
            data.html = html;
            
            fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
                if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
                res.json('works'); 
            });
        })(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if it works:

```
const fs = require('fs');


app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
 res.app.render(data.template, { //requires a nice template
            data: data
        }, async function (err, html) {
            data.html = html;
            try {
            const response = await fs.promises.readFile('credentials.json');
            res.json('works');
            } catch (e) {
             console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
            }
         }})
        });
```

Comment: It is still not working.  FS works outside ouf res.app.render, and res.app.render does it's job. I am not getting an error from catch. Just getting server error (500)